# how make a GridView with Dynamic Data and Autogenerated Columns show only specific columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic, scaffolding

Hi all:
I am working on a Dynamic Data project using scaffolding on VS2010, and I make it work very nice with all tables, it shows every table with all fields, Edit, Insert, view-related-items, etc. But i have some tables with too many fields, i would like to restrict or limit the number of columns to display on some tables. How do I do that? I tried with the Custom pages, specifying the fields I'd like, creating ItemTemplates, DynamicField, and worked fine, showing the columns specified, but then the autogenerated columns, specifically those "View Related-Table-Items", stopped to show themselves...
Thanks in advance
Pinchete

Comment: not clear, please,explain clearly what you want to do? or what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the grid not to autogenerate colums with this in the markup

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

Comment: sorry if I didnt make it clear, I DO want to use autogenerate columns, but only for some Fields(columns)

Comment: @xpincho I'm pretty sure there's not a way to disable AutoGenerateColumns on only a few columns. When AutoGenerateColumns IS enabled, no columns will show up at all; You have to specify each and everyone you want to show. You'll have to find how to add the "View Related-Table-Items" in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: You can not just `AutoGenerateColumns="Some"` It is an all or nothing switch.  You can define which columns you want or you can have all of them show up.  You could create a view that only shows the columns you want or you could create a query/stored procedure that will only return the columns you want.

Comment: Correct.  Choose: AutoGenerateColumns="False" or AutoGenerateColumns="True"